# Problema con margin 0 en * y linear-gradient en html

Tags: css

Aquí está mi código:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(9,9,121,1), rgba(0,212,255,1));
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="form1 shape"></div>
            <div class="form2 shape"></div>
            <div class="form3 shape"></div>
            <div class="form4 shape"></div>
            <div class="form5 shape"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Quería practicar flexbox y diferentes estilos en los div  dentro de body, por ello quería ponerle un fondo con linear-gradient al documento html y quería ponerle un margin 0, padding 0 y box-sizing: border-box a todos los elementos usando *, pero si ponía margin:0 desaparecía el color de fondo, lo que quiero saber es porqué pasa eso.
Gracias por su atención :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto pasa porque en tu código eliminaste los `border`, `padding` y `margin`, y al no tener contenido alguno la altura de tu HTML es cero.

El fondo se mostraría si:

- Agregas una altura mayor a cero (desde 1px)
- Das `border`, `padding` y/o `margin` a cualquiera de los elementos
- Seteas la propiedad `bacground-size`
- Colocas contenido con dimensión, como por ejemplo: `<div class="form1 shape">CONTENIDO</div>`
- O cualquier cosa que haga crecer la altura del HTML

Es decir al faltar todos los elementos anteriores, no se renderizará el `linear-gradient` y ese sería el motivo.

Ahora, la razón de fondo de este comportamiento la desconozco. Para mi es un **bug**, pienso que posiblemente el algoritmo para generar la imagen del `linear-gradient` se detiene en algún punto al ser la altura (o la anchura) menor o igual a cero.

Según la [documentación](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#special-backgrounds) el background para las etiquetas `HTML` y `BODY` deberían convertirse en el background del lienzo y a su vez del viewport, el cual si tiene un tamaño, por lo que no existe razón para este comportamiento, el cual solo tiene sentido para otras etiquetas distintas a HTML y BODY

Si haces `background:red` si mostrará el color de fondo, porque hace justamente lo descrito anteriormente, por eso (vuelvo a repetir) me parece un bug del algoritmo de los `<gradient>`

Answer (score 0):

El problema radica en que al "resetear" tanto las dimensiones como las propiedades de espacio interior y exterior de la etiqueta **html** se ocupa ningún espacio definido en dentro del contenido, por lo que es necesario volver a otorgarle una dimensión concreta para que pueda aplicarle las propiedades de **background** que necesitas. En este caso una solución que resuelve el problema es darle un **height** en el que pueda aplicar dichas propiedades:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html{
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(9,9,121,1), rgba(0,212,255,1)); height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="content">
            <div class="form1 shape"></div>
            <div class="form2 shape"></div>
            <div class="form3 shape"></div>
            <div class="form4 shape"></div>
            <div class="form5 shape"></div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

A continuación comparto un enlace de interés sobre el uso del borrado de propiedades heredadas a través de del selector "*" y como se puede operar con ello: [Selectores CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Selectors/Type_Class_and_ID_Selectors#el_selector_universal)